# Python: Keyboard input without repeat delay

Tags: python, windows, input, tkinter, keyboard

For those who don't know, repeat delay is the slight pause between, when holding down a key, the letter first appearing and it repeating. This might be a useful feature when typing, however when you start to write games, it becomes  very annoying. An example is when you need to move a character; it will move a tiny bit, pause, and then start to move again. Tkinter code:

```
ball = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)
def move():
   canvas.move(ball, 0, 3)
canvas.bind_all("<space>", move)
```

If space is pressed, the ball will move down 3 pixels, pause, and then start moving normally. I was wondering if there is any way to avoid that pause, for example a module that reads directly from the keyboard, and not the windows-processed keyboard. I know that it is possible to "cheat" by, for example, automatically running the function when you expect the delay to occur; sadly that is inaccurate and can result in choppy movement. Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, you want a key *press* event, rather than a key *type* event. You have to do the repeat yourself until the key release happens. This allows you to control the repeat rate, too.

Comment: @o11c: be aware that your suggestion may not work -- some keyboards automatically send a stream of press-release events even when you are simply pressing and holding the key.

Comment: The solution to that problem is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-keyrelease-events

Answer (score 0):

Make a recursion loop for while it is pressed. Or that's how I do it, at least.

```
moving = False
def move():
  global moving
  moving = True
def stop_moving():
  global moving
  moving = False

def myloop():
  global moving
  if moving == True:
    canvas.move(ball, 0, 3)
  root.after(1, myloop)

root.bind('<space>', lambda e: move())
root.bind('<KeyRelease-space>', lambda e: stop_moving())
```

just make sure you call your loop once before root.mainloop()

```
#like this
root.after(1, myloop)
root.mainloop()
```