# How to run a method on keypress in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry field, and as I type into the data field, I want a method, that updates a treeview widget to be ran. Currently, I can type in a search parameter, then press a 'search' button and it will run the method to search through the treeview to find specified clients, but I want to the treeview to be updating whilst typing into the entry, not by a button press

I am unsure as to weather this is possible, if it should be doing by binding keys or if there is a way using the event loop to achieve this?

Comment: Have you learned about the `bind` method available on every widget? It's a fundamental part of just about every tkinter tutorial.

Comment: Yes, @BryanOakley but as I stated bind works by binding one key at a time, and I want one method to be bound to every key simultaneously, which looking at previous posts is not possible.

Comment: `bind` does more than bind to one key at a time. You can use it to bind to any key press or key release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this SO post:
[TkInter keypress, keyrelease events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-keyrelease-events)

Essentially:

```
from Tkinter import *
def keyup(e):
    pass;
    # e.char contains the pressed key if you need that info
    # use your search function here
```

Edit (Sorry I forgot this):

You'll need to bind the keyup function to your widget with something like:

```
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup) # you can also bind to a search widget
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.