# Is it possible to pass a function to a class and have it be stored so that it can be called in response to an event?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add keyboard control to a Tkinter programme I am using to control a robot. My goal is to have certain keys run a motion command when they are pressed down, and a stop command when they are released.

With help from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-keyrelease-events) I have managed to get this working, but this method requires me to write the function calls into the custom KeyTracker class used to debounce the keys, which is inconvenient. Is there some way for me to pass the functions I want the key to call as arguments to the KeyTracker class when I make a new instance of it? For example, for the W key, this would be something along the lines of either:

```py
# To bind events to the press and release of the W key:
self.key_tracker_W = KeyTracker('W', 'w', self.key_pressed_W, self.key_released_W)
top.bind( "<KeyPress-w>",   self.key_tracker_W.report_key_press   )
top.bind( "<KeyRelease-w>", self.key_tracker_W.report_key_release )
```

or

```py
# To bind events to the press and release of the w key:
self.key_tracker_W = KeyTracker('W', 'w')
top.bind( "<KeyPress-w>",   self.key_tracker_W.report_key_press(self.key_pressed_W) )
top.bind( "<KeyRelease-w>", self.key_tracker_W.report_key_release(self.key_released_W) )
```

This way, I could use the class as many times as I needed to without having to add code to it for each new use.

I made a scaled down example programme. Once the window is open, if you press the W, A, S, or D keys, corresponding text is printed to the shell.

```py
##############################################################################################
## IMPORT LIBRARIES:

import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

##############################################################################################
## Debouncer For Keyboard Events:
class KeyTracker():
    #=====================================================================================
    """
    The code for this class was modified from an example found at:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-keyrelease-events
    
    The KeyPress event gets called twice, but that isn't a problem for my needs.
    """
    #=====================================================================================
    def __init__(self, KEY_U, KEY_L):
        self.key_U             = KEY_U
        self.key_L             = KEY_L
        self.last_press_time   = 0
        self.last_release_time = 0
    #=====================================================================================
    def is_pressed(self):
        return time.time() - self.last_press_time < 0.1
    #=====================================================================================
    def report_key_press(self, event):
        if (event.keysym == self.key_U or event.keysym == self.key_L):
            if not( self.is_pressed() ):
                print("Key Pressed")
                
                # I don't like having to have this if statement here:
                if   (self.key_U == 'W'):  app.key_pressed_W()
                elif (self.key_U == 'A'):  app.key_pressed_A()
                elif (self.key_U == 'S'):  app.key_pressed_S()
                elif (self.key_U == 'D'):  app.key_pressed_D()
                # I would rather be calling a function that was passed to the class as an argument.
            
            self.last_press_time = time.time()
    #=====================================================================================
    def report_key_release(self, event):
        if (event.keysym == self.key_U or event.keysym == self.key_L):
            self.timer = threading.Timer(0.1, self.report_key_release_callback, args = [event])
            self.timer.start()
    #=====================================================================================
    def report_key_release_callback(self, event):
        if not(self.is_pressed()):
            print("Key Released")
            
            # I don't like having to have this if statement here:
            if   (self.key_U == 'W'):  app.key_released_W()
            elif (self.key_U == 'A'):  app.key_released_A()
            elif (self.key_U == 'S'):  app.key_released_S()
            elif (self.key_U == 'D'):  app.key_released_D()
            # I would rather be calling a function that was passed to the class as an argument.
        
        self.last_release_time = time.time()
    #=====================================================================================
##############################################################################################
## Class For Creating The Main Window:
class CLASS_Window_Main(tk.Frame):
    #=====================================================================================
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  # super().__init__(master)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.grid( sticky = tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W )   # Resize window contents when window is resized.
        self.GUI_Create_Widgets()
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #=====================================================================================
    def GUI_Create_Widgets(self):
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Create Window:
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(    0, weight = 1 )
        top.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Bind Window Resized Event:
        top.bind( "<Configure>", self.GUI_Window_Resized )
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ## Bind Keyboard Events:
        
        # Bind events to the W key:
        self.key_tracker_W = KeyTracker('W','w')
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-w>",   self.key_tracker_W.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-W>",   self.key_tracker_W.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-w>", self.key_tracker_W.report_key_release )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-W>", self.key_tracker_W.report_key_release )
        
        
        # Bind events to the A key:
        self.key_tracker_A = KeyTracker('A','a')
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-a>",   self.key_tracker_A.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-A>",   self.key_tracker_A.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-a>", self.key_tracker_A.report_key_release )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-A>", self.key_tracker_A.report_key_release )
        
        
        # Bind events to the S key:
        self.key_tracker_S = KeyTracker('S','s')
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-s>",   self.key_tracker_S.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-S>",   self.key_tracker_S.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-s>", self.key_tracker_S.report_key_release )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-S>", self.key_tracker_S.report_key_release )
        
        
        # Bind events to the D key:
        self.key_tracker_D = KeyTracker('D','d')
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-d>",   self.key_tracker_D.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyPress-D>",   self.key_tracker_D.report_key_press   )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-d>", self.key_tracker_D.report_key_release )
        top.bind( "<KeyRelease-D>", self.key_tracker_D.report_key_release )
        
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Run This Function When The Window Is Resized:
    def GUI_Window_Resized(self, event):
        print("The window was resized")
    #=====================================================================================
    ## Functions To Be Run In Response To Keys:
    
    def key_pressed_W(self):
        print("KEYPRESS = W")
    
    def key_released_W(self):
        print("KEYRELEASE = W")
    
    
    
    def key_pressed_A(self):
        print("KEYPRESS = A")
    
    def key_released_A(self):
        print("KEYRELEASE = A")
    
    
    
    def key_pressed_S(self):
        print("KEYPRESS = S")
    
    def key_released_S(self):
        print("KEYRELEASE = S")
    
    
    
    def key_pressed_D(self):
        print("KEYPRESS = D")
    
    def key_released_D(self):
        print("KEYRELEASE = D")
    
    #=====================================================================================
##############################################################################################
## RUN PROGRAMME:

print("Programme Start")

# Run the Tkinter programme:
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")          # Set the default size of the window.
app = CLASS_Window_Main()         # Create CLASS_Window_Main instance.
app.master.title("Window Title")  # Set the title of the window.
app.mainloop()                    # Start CLASS_Window_Main.
##############################################################################################
```

I know that I could just use what I have now as is, but my inner perfectionist keeps nagging me about it, saying that he wants the class to be "more versatile". Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I undestand problem but you can pass function to other function or class as any other value. You already pass function to `bind()` . In Tkinter you also pass function in `tkButton(... command=function_name)` or `root.after(time, function_name)` Often it is called as `callback`

Comment: @furas OK, but how do I run a function that has been passed as an argument? Say we take the function `def report_key_press(self, event, callback):`. How do I get the programme to run the function that was passed to `callback` at a specific point within report_key_press?

Comment: you use `()` to run it - `callback()` - btw. simple example: `display = print` and later `display("Hello World")`

Comment: @furas Thanks! My inner perfectionist is happy now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a function to a class and have it be stored so that it can be called in response to an event?

Yes, you can pass functions around like that.

In your example you just need to save the callback in the `__init__` method, and then use it later.

```
class KeyTracker():
    def __init__(self, KEY_U, KEY_L, press_callback, release_callback):
        self.press_callback = press_callback
        self.release_callback = release_callback
        ...
```

You use it later just like you would any function:

```
class KeyTracker():
    def report_key_release_callback(self, event):
        # call the stored callback
        self.release_callback(event)
```